# Isekai manga where main character was a male scientist and was reincarnated into female magic user

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I have read this manga for a while now (possibly more than 3 months). The main character was reincarnated into another world in which he (she in this case) lives in the forest and has almost no interaction with other human.

She has the power to create (more like synthesize) things from his past life which in turn, makes for her a movable house in the wood. Then she was met by villager begging for help for the disease so she create a medicine for them for free.

However, some people in the village then come and ask for her help again but this time coerce her to give them a free medicine (and with the mob of villagers in the end). She then moves her house out and the first pair of villagers who were asking about the medicine regretted their actions. This story also has a comedic part where Main Character accidentally gained ecchi skill when she looks at herself (and synthesize garments for herself).

Comment: Was this online?  What site was it on?  Can you give any details of the art style or the appearance of the main character?

Comment: It is a published (in book) manga but I read online. Don't remember the site either but the art style is more on shonen style and I don't exactly remember the appearance of the main character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manga is called "i dont really get it but it seem like iv reincarnated in another world"
I know this cuz i red it

Comment: A-hah! That's what I am looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to add additional information as to why this matches